# changement jquery version error with flot

Tags: jquery, graph, version, flot

I am using jquery and flot in my application. All working well.
I want to update the version of jquery from 1.8 to the latest. When I do this my graph are blank. There is no error in console.
I didn't find anything on google. Have anyone heard of that?

Comment: You may want to add the migrate patch - http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/

Comment: Thanks a lot it solved my problem, but I don't know what is the initial problem?

Comment: Because there are many changes between 1.8 and the most recent the migrate plugin bridges those changes. It seems you should have seen errors in your console without the migrate plugin.

Comment: I use the version not min and all error are explain in the console. So thanks a lot for your help